# Stencil test doesn't work at all in Unity when I am using a custom shader

Tags: unity, shaders, shaderlab

I am using Unity 2019.3 and I have a custom shader A which contains the code

```
Stencil{
     Ref 5
     Comp Equal
     Pass Keep
}
```

And the other custom shader B contains the code

```
Stencil{
     Ref 5
     Comp Always
     Pass Replace
}
```

The stencil test can do the right thing only if I add `Fallback "Diffuse"` in B, otherwise, it's never working. And A has no code related to `Fallback`.

Since shader A is using for post processing and I did something like

```
    buffer.SetGlobalTexture(ShaderID._MainTex,source);
    buffer.SetRenderTarget(destination);
    buffer.DrawMesh(mesh,Matrix4x4.identity,material,0,pass);
```

The `material` uses shader A.

Does this cause the issue because before today, I never use the `Fallback` during stencil test.

PS. You can use [this](https://github.com/OtakuAndFitness/TechnicalNote) and scene named SSS as example. In that scene the shader named Unlit/PBR has this issue. If you delete `Fallback "Diffuse` in that shader, the post processing effect never works.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information about what these shaders are doing or how you're using them to reproduce the issue. Can you ensure your question contains a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example?

Comment: Please post the MCVE in your question itself, not as an external link.

Comment: I've edited the question, now you'll have a more clear view of this issue